# Manage reserve NPCs' skills

Tags: ps3, mass-effect

I've been looking for a way to easily manage the skills and/or inventory of my reserve NPCs (the NPCs I've recruited who are not part of the current shore party).  So far, the only way to manage their inventory that I've seen is to access their lockers on the Normandy.  I haven't found any way to manage the NPCs' skills unless they're with me in a shore party.

Have I missed something, or is this a feature that's just not in the game?

*NOTE:  I'm on the PS3, so any mods available for PC would be of no use.*

Comment: Can you not manage their inventory when they're part of your shore party?

Comment: @RavenDreamer You can, and it's even easier to manage multiple characters' inventories when in a shore party than when on the Normandy. However, the shore party is limited to 2 NPCs while your total number of recruited NPCs may be up to 6. The only way I've found to manage all seven characters' (6 NPCs + 1 PC) inventories from one place is aboard the Normandy. However, in that interface you're limited to handling one character's inventory at a time. Also, when in a shore party, you can easily manage the shore party characters' skills. But when on the Normandy, you can only work with the PC's.

Comment: Then I regret to inform you that's the best it's gonna get. If you continue with the series, Mass Effect 2 handles inventory management and party skills much better.

Comment: @RavenDreamer If that's the answer, then that's what it is - please write an answer to that effect so it can be voted on & accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mass Effect, it is only possible to level up squadmates who are actually in your party.

While you can set party members to level-up their skills automatically, if you want to customize your teammates yourself, you'll have to actually take them with you as a shore party, somewhere.